# phpmailer не работает на поддомене

Tags: php, phpmailer

На нескольких сайтах использую PHPMailer и абсолютно идентичные скрипты. Везде работают отлично, а вот на сайте который находится на поддомене, не работает. Даже проводился эксперемент, рабочий сайт был перемещен в поддомен, а письма работать перестали. Сам хостинг на рег ру. Может с ним что-то не то? Или всё же PHPMailer так работает и что с ним сделать?

```html
Sending with mail()
Sendmail path: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f info@first-sport.ru/
Envelope sender: info@first-sport.ru
To: fullstack@yandex.ru
Subject: =?utf-8?B?0J7QsdC90L7QstC70LXQvdC40LUg0LTQsNC90L3Ri9GFIQ==?=
Headers: Date: Sat, 23 Mar 2024 18:58:42 +0300From: info@first-sport.ruMessage-ID: <dJEThHNOgFXft3CN5h99x4QFiVBtTzDXANug9riIU@logistic.new-athletics.ru>X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.6.5 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="b1_dJEThHNOgFXft3CN5h99x4QFiVBtTzDXANug9riIU"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Additional params: -finfo@first-sport.ru
Result: false
Could not instantiate mail function.
```

```html
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
$mail->setFrom($config->getMail());
$mail->addAddress($data['email']);
$mail->Subject = $content['subject'];
$mail->msgHTML($this->render('mailer/' . $file . '.html.twig', $content));
$mail->send();
```